# postgresql mybatis date format?

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

Please tell me how to change the calculation method of this format

before is feasible

```
now() + interval '3' month  as end_date
```

after not executable

```
now() + interval #{value} month  as end_date
```

please..

Success Thank you all for your help!
now() + make_interval(months => #{value}::integer)  as end_date

Comment: I don't know mybatis, but what about: `now() + make_interval(months => #{value}) as end_date`

Comment: Thanks for helping me organize the article :) 
let's try

Comment: Not successful, but thanks!

Comment: Then mybatis is messing up something. `#{value}` needs to be an integer value, not a string (that is enclosed in single quotes). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=785c3f07b23c6e15c1cd59efbfe27545

Comment: make_interval(months => #{perid_cd}::integer)   
Success Thank you all for your help!